# SQL Server Exact Table Transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

How do you achieve an exact transpose in SQL?

```
Month | High | Low | Avg
-------------------------
Jan   | 10    | 9   | 9.5
-------------------------
Feb   | 8  |  7   | 7.5
-------------------------
Mar   | 7    | 6   | 6.5
-------------------------
```

Result

```
------ Jan | Feb | Mar
--------------------------
High-- 10  | 8   | 7
--------------------------
Low--  9   | 7   | 6
--------------------------
Avg    9.5 | 7.5 | 6.5
--------------------------
```

Comment: Please search the site for PIVOT/UNPIVOT examples. This question gets asked at least 5 times a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will first have to *unpivot* the `High`, `Low` and `Avg` columns by turning those into rows. Then you will apply the *pivot* function to convert the `month` values into columns. (See: MSDN [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) docs)

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` to unpivot.  The code to unpivot is:

```
select t.month, 
  c.col, 
  c.value
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values ('High', high), ('Low', Low), ('Avg', Avg)
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04108/1). This gives the result in a format that can then be pivoted by month:

```
| MONTH |  COL | VALUE |
------------------------
|   Jan | High |    10 |
|   Jan |  Low |     9 |
|   Jan |  Avg |   9.5 |
|   Feb | High |     8 |
|   Feb |  Low |     7 |
```

Once the data is in rows, you apply the pivot function, so the code will be:

```
select col, Jan, Feb, Mar
from
(
  select t.month, 
    c.col, 
    c.value
  from yourtable t
  cross apply
  (
    values ('High', high), ('Low', Low), ('Avg', Avg)
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for month in (Jan, Feb, Mar)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0504/3). This gives the result:

```
|  COL | JAN | FEB | MAR |
--------------------------
|  Avg | 9.5 | 7.5 | 6.5 |
| High |  10 |   8 |   7 |
|  Low |   9 |   7 |   6 |
```

Since you are pivoting month names, I doubt that you need a dynamic SQL version of this but if you had an unknown number of values, then you could use dynamic sql to get the result.

Comment: Thanks really helpful. "Cross Apply" is exactly what I was looking for Thanks a ton!

Comment: Needed to change the syntax a little for SQL Server 2008 R2
cross apply
(
    SELECT 'High',t.[high]
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Low',t.[low]
    union
    SELECT 'Average',t.[Average]
) c (col, value))d

Answer (score 1):

Great use for `pivot` and `unpivot`:

```
with t as (
    select 'Jan' as mon, cast(10.0 as float) as high, cast(9.0 as float) as low, cast(9.5 as float) as average union all
    select 'Feb' as mon, 8.0, 7.0, 7.5
   )
select stat, Jan, Feb, Mar
from (select mon, STAT, value
      from t
      unpivot  (value for stat in (high, low, average)) u
     ) t
pivot (max(value) for mon in (Jan, Feb, Mar)) as pt
```